# Soundblaster Audigy has only left channel, but works fine in Windows

Tags: sound

I have an older PC running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 with a 2TB main disk drive.  I shrunk the primary Windows partition to make room for 2 different Linux distributions (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Fedora 23), so now I have the ability to boot into each of the three different OS choices.

My machine has a Soundblaster Audigy PCI audio card installed which works just fine when I boot to Windows 7.  However, when I boot to either Ubuntu or Fedora, sound only comes from the left channel of that sound card.

Has anyone else experienced this, and (if so) how did you remedy this situation?

THANKS!